# How does 802.11a,b,g,n,ac and channel factor into sniffing with wireshark?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I have been playing around with wireshark lately and am wondering how your 802.11 version as well as channel impact packet capture? If my router uses 802.11a,g,n and ac and my wifi adapter uses 802.11b,g,n and ac how will this work? How do I know which channel to use when there is one for 2.4GHz and another for 5GHz?

Comment: Wireshark works best when the traffic is going *through* the capture device. See https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your monitor mode sniffer's Wi-Fi radio can only be tuned to one channel at a time, so you can only sniff one channel at a time, as a general rule. There can be some situations where you can get bleed-through of transmissions from overlapping channels and such, but as a general rule, you can only sniff on one channel at a time.

If you have a simultaneous dual-band wireless router (supporting both 2.4GHz and 5GHz at the same time), then it's like you have two APs in one box. The 2.4GHz AP will be on one 2.4GHz channel, and the 5GHz AP will be on one 5GHz channel. Note that if multiple APs are publishing the same network name (SSID), then it's up to the clients to choose which AP to join, and when to roam to a different one. So if you want to capture traffic to/from a specific client, and you only have one monitor-mode Wi-Fi adapter that you're using Wireshark with, you'll want to use separate SSIDs on each AP (i.e. on each band of your dual-band wireless router), so you can control which AP the target client joins, so you know which channel to capture on.

Wireshark relies on your monitor-mode Wi-Fi adapter to receive the radio waves and demodulate them into bits, so Wireshark can only capture traffic that your monitor-mode Wi-Fi adapter has the hardware to receive and demodulate. So the channel, channel width, number of spatial streams (MIMO receive chains), and modulation schemes you can sniff are determined by the hardware in your monitor-mode Wi-Fi adapter.

If you're asked to choose a channel width for monitor mode, you can default to just using the widest channel width your monitor-mode adapter supports for that channel. An adapter set to, say 80MHz-wide channels, will automatically capture any 40- or 20MHz-wide transmissions on that channel set.

Comment: OK this definitely clarifies a few things for me. I'm still learning and really appreciate the detailed answer!